# Exactly what does it take for the moderation team to understand the question SERIOUS

Tags: discussion

Obviously that reason is being used illegitimately, but may I ask, what is the actual reason?

I guess, they want to try and make the site more serious, but how are these mods qualified to know what is serious, I wonder? Basically, I'm not sharing in their vision!

Comment: It's hard to know what you are asking without some examples. Could you link to one or two questions where you think someone made a mistake? Alternatively, what is your vision and how does it differ from how you perceive the moderator's vision? It will be a lot easier to have this discussion if we know what your concerns are in detail.

Comment: this is one example, which has since been clarified http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21221/is-mental-illness-really-an-illness i asked the question in the title then repeated it in the first paragraph. it's clear now though that one can't draw from one's own experiences in legitimatising a question, i guess ?

Comment: Seems like you asked a very similar question here: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21167/is-mental-illness-really-a-disease That question seems to have recieved several thoughtful answers. So I'm curious why you'd ask it again. Also, why did you re-ask this meta question rather than edit it?

Comment: sorry i don't understand ??

Comment: @MATHEMATICIAN I think Jon is saying it looks like a duplicate...?

Comment: it isn't i don't think

Comment: and this http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21268/how-would-you-de-construct-hieronymo-is-mad-again what's wrong with this we all know the drone army will close it but why if not an uncanny feeling they aren't up to answering it lol

Answer (score -3, accepted):

in effect, the mod team want to control the conversation, steering away the site from the casual, the poorly informed, and the chatty.

so only ask question that the mods would ask.